# Blog posts all on homepage or teasers that link to main post?

Tags: blog

Which is better? Which will lead to more readership and/or SEO? Currently showing a synopsis on homepage that links to full blog post. What would be the better approach: the whole blog post on posts feed or shortened synopsis with a "read more" link?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer teasers with "read more".

Google will have no problem indexing the content on your home page.  There are two problems with that:

1. Google will generally choose the home page to index over the permalink because the home page has more reputation.
2. Content eventually falls off the home page.

Users get frustrated when they click to your site and have trouble finding the content that has fallen off the page.  This causes them to use the back button and look at other sites.   This user behavior causes your rankings to fall.

If you can, always have Google index content on the permalinks. It leads to a better user experience and better rankings.

Answer (score 0):

Homepage is the image of a website. That's why you better show more content in homepage. That's why your visitors have chance to read more content of you. It's also better for your Search Engine Optimization cause you are better Internal link from homepage. Share about 20-50 content in homepage.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are suggesting.   Are you suggesting that the number of items on the homepage be increased?

Answer (score 0):

Having whole blog posts on the homepage makes it hard to scan for relevant information from a user point of view.

I'm not entirely sure, but it may also affect your SEO, as Google may see it as duplicate content (on homepage and on the blog post page), which will penalise your rankings.

Comment: I don't think google will penalise as this is what the blogspot doing for many years.